# Xamarin , Azure mobile apps and asp.net core 2.2

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am building a mobile app with a admin portal . 
I am using Azure Mobile apps with classic .Net back end .

Can I use .NET Core with Azure Mobile apps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately , it is not available at present, Please take a look at similar issue:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9254

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/issues/215

Also you could see

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client#future-of-azure-mobile-apps

for more Azure Mobile Apps plans.